# How to force item in a row stay in middle and the other oe beside it

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have a container which is in purple color
I want the Red box force staying in middle exactly and the Green box be flex beside it.
How is it possible?

I don't want to both average in center. Only red one.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMbXp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid is better option for this purpose, and by green box being flexed you probably meant box-alignment properties you generally in flex, which can also be used in grid. **This layout is easy to achieve in flex-box too but its just dividing the container into 3 elements(let's say 33% each) and then applying flex again in those nested elements**, In fact we did a similar thing by applying grid .With grid implementation it should look something like this:

```css
.parent{
  width: 80%;
  height:50px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  margin:auto;
}

.child1{
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#ff8080;
  text-align:center;
}

.child2{
   grid-column: 3 / span 1;
   height:40px;
   width:100px;
   background-color:lightgreen;
   text-align:center;
}

.box-styles{
  border-radius:20px;
  border:solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent box-styles">
  <div class="child1 box-styles text-style">
    centered
  </div>
  <div class="child2 box-styles text-style">
    flexed
  </div>
</div>
```